# Get the source of flash.display package

Tags: actionscript-3

i need the source of flash.display package so that i can get the better idea of the graphics and vectors. So anyone can help me out to get this package.

Comment: here You have whole documentation : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/package-detail.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ask http://adobe.com about that, global code is not open source :)

Answer (score 0):

That package source is not available as ActionScript. It has only ActionScript interfaces, while the actual implementation is native-level and built into Flash Player.